# How to write a program that will allow a laser to continually move up throughout the program

Tags: java, drawing

I have a program in which I am trying to make something similar to space invaders but I do not know how to adjust the path of the laser so it continually moves up.

I tried to make it with a variable and the variable and being added to and then repainting.

```java
dx = 0;
dy = 0;

if(up)
{
  if(pressup >0)
  {
    currentlocationx = mouseclicklocationx;
    currentlocationy = mouseclicklocationy;
    pressup--;
  )
  relicfirework.paintIcon(this, g, mouseclicklocationx, mouseclicklocationy);
  dy = 200;

  System.out.println(currentlocationy);
  System.out.println(currentlocationx);
}
```

My results are that the laser appears on the rocket, but when I press the up arrow, the laser does not move. I want the laser to move upwards in a path.

Comment: Is that `)` after `pressup--;` a `}` in your code?

Comment: yes the ) symbol is after the variable pressup--;